# How to extract the value from multiple checkbox and merge them in 1 texbox field on Infopath?

Tags: checkbox, textbox, merge, infopath, infopath2010

I 've created an Infopath 2010 form. It contains some checkbox, the user can choose more than 1 checkbox, and I want to merge these values into 1 textbox. here is the example:

- [ ] Value 1 <=this is the checkbox
- [*] Value 2 <=this is the checkbox (selected)
- [*] Value 3 <=this is the checkbox (selected)
- [Value2, Value3, and some text that add manually] <=this is the textbox that I want to merge the value and add this value to 1 column in database.

can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a rule on each of those checkboxes that runs when the checkbox is changed. Each rule would look up the other values and text, concatenate them how you need it, and set the value of the final textbox to that string.